# In my anaconda's environment tensor, I have two pips . How can I uninstall the old version? my OS is windows10

Tags: python, anaconda

There are two pips in my environment, I use the command "conda list" to list them

> pip  18.0
>
> pip  9.0.1 py35_1

I want to remove pip 9.0.1, how can I do it?

Comment: Does `conda remove pip` work?

Comment: This command will remove python, i can't do it.

Comment: Running a conda command can't uninstall python since Conda itself requires python

Comment: `conda remove` removes packages, not python itself.  `conda -h` says: ` remove       Remove a list of packages from a specified conda environment.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `conda uninstall pip=*version*`?
You could also run `conda uninstall pip` (possibly `conda uninstall pip*`) and remove both versions, then install the latest version of pip after that.

Two versions of pip in a single conda env should not happen through the usual update processes. Either you mistakenly installed the second, or something went very wrong with anaconda. If you suspect that it is something on anaconda's end, then this is a good opportunity for some spring cleaning. Export and then remove the environment, update and clean conda, then either:

- Rebuild the environment by removing anything you don't need from your exported environment file and importing this environment again. Then run another `conda update --all` to ensure you are on the latest version for these packages.
- OR Create a fresh environment, manually go through your exported environment and install only your most-used packages. I'd recommend this one, to get a better understanding of what dependencies your projects actually need.

**Addendum:**
Kota Mori comments that:

> Two pip's can happen if you: 1. conda istall pip, then 2. pip install pip --upgrade.

I did not consider this in my original answer. The [Conda user guide](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html) does not explicitly advise against installing packages through a non-conda version of pip: Anything installed by your pip 18.0, is in the currently active conda environment.

> Pip packages do not have all the features of conda packages, and we recommend first trying to install any package with conda. [...] To gain the benefits of conda integration, be sure to install pip inside the currently active conda environment, and then install packages with that instance of pip.

However, (and this is speculation) given that Anaconda aims to simplify package management for Python and R, it may be developed for the pip version delivered by conda. Delivering v10 would then be deliberate. I would personally be wary of unintended side effects and would choose to recreate my environment if I cannot cleanly uninstall v18 and return to v10, or whichever version is currently distributed through conda.

Comment: Two pip's can happen if you:
1. `conda istall pip`, then
2. `pip install pip --upgrade`.

But in this case you have `pip 18.0` with build by `<pip>`, which slightly differs from the question description, where "build" column is empty.

Comment: That is a very good point. I see Anaconda as a semi-curated environment - where delivering a specific version of pip is likely to be deliberate. Upgrading pip though pip didn't occur to me in that context.

Comment: I don't usually do that either.  But, since `pip` in the conda default is still version 10, `pip` always suggests to run the upgrade command.  If you follow that, you get two pip's on the conda list.